# return value get from promise in higher scope

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to have simple function returning the name, here's the code:

```
        getName(entity, id) {
            const promise = userServices.getName(entity, id).then((data) => {
                return data;
            });
            //I want to return 'data' value here
        }
```

I'm using **vue** and I know I can make another `data() variable`, but I don't want to use it for single function. Is there an other easy way? Can I create a `variable` in the function that can be accessed inside promise?

Comment: there is no way to do this, you can only return a Promise resolving to this data since operation inside of the getName function is asynchronous, unless you return like an object that will be later updated, (which is most likely not what you want since there is no way to guarantee the value being written into it before accesing it)

Comment: `returning an object that is later updated`- literally the definition of promise... @KrzysztofKrzeszewski

Comment: yes exactly, it is what a promise is, however in such a case he could use a non-promise syntax, which might be needed in some particular cases

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski I kinda disagree... could you give me an example where its needed where promises can't help? There are so many implementations and libraries for promises, including tons of utilities in the native promises library, that I find it very hard to imagine a scenario where implementing your own promise-like logic would be better...

Answer (score 4):

What you're trying to do is impossible. You can't get an asynchronous data into synchronous code, this is why promises exists.

you have 2 options basically:

1. async / await

   ```
   async getName(entity, id) {
       await data = userServices.getName(entity, id);
       return data;
   };
   ```

This is viable, but remember that async functions return promises behind the scenes, so the operation still remains async. This means when you invoke `getName` in your primary code, it will go into event loop and only execute when main code is done.

2. return the promise

   ```
   getName(entity, id) {
       return userServices.getName(entity, id);
   }
   ```

Then you can chain the `.then` outside of the function, meaning in the main code scope, so you can use variables / invoke functions / update state that are found in the main code scope using that returned value. But, it is still a `.then` clause of a promise- means this value won't be available through *all* the main code scope, but only inside the `.then` and again- it is still an async operation.